# Message Forwarding Processor maximum redelivery attempts issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working on a project involving message stores and message forwarding processors within WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. The issue I've noticed is that in case of a problem with the endpoint specified for the processor, the message gets redelivered four times the number I set for `max.delivery.attempts` parameter before the processor deactivates.

The definition from [this page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Message+Forwarding+Processor) says that the number represents the "*Maximum redelivery attempts before deactivating the processor*".

Here is my message processor configuration:

```
<messageProcessor name="msgProcessor" class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" targetEndpoint="myEP" messageStore="messageStoreTest" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="interval">200</parameter>
   <parameter name="client.retry.interval">5000</parameter>
   <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">1</parameter>
   <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">main</parameter>
   <parameter name="message.processor.fault.sequence">fault</parameter>
   <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

Anybody else noticed this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the Message Processor component of the ESB, affecting the 4.9.0 version.

The JIRA issue for this is located [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3323), with the bug being currently unresolved.